# SOAP-Lite-1.14 `make test` errors

Tags: perl, soap

Using 64-bit Cygwin v2.0.4(0.287/5/3), I manually downloaded SOAP-Lite-1.14 from CPAN and then ran `perl Makefile.PL`, `make`, and then `make test`.  (I did not remove the t folder first).  However, the `make test` finds errors in the .pm files.

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for SOAP::Lite
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

$ make
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Packager.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Header.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Client.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Constants.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/LOOPBACK.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Packager.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/SOM.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema1999.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/MAILTO.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Test.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Schema.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Apache/SOAP.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Trace.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/POP3.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Deserializer.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Server.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Data.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/TCP.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Utils.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/IO.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Serializer.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_2.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Utils.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_1.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/LOCAL.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/SOAP/Fault.pod (unchanged)
cp bin/SOAPsh.pl blib/script/SOAPsh.pl
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/SOAPsh.pl
cp bin/stubmaker.pl blib/script/stubmaker.pl
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/stubmaker.pl
Manifying 2 pod documents
Manifying 21 pod documents


$ make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/Issues/*.t t/SOAP/*.t t/SOAP/Lite/*.t t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/*.t t/SOAP/Schema/*.t t/SOAP/Transport/*.t t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/*.t
t/01-core.t .................................. ok
t/010-serializer.t ........................... ok
t/012-cloneable.t ............................ ok
t/013-array-deserialization.t ................ ok
t/014_UNIVERSAL_use.t ........................ ok
t/015_UNIVERSAL_can.t ........................ ok
t/02-payload.t ............................... ok
t/03-server.t ................................ ok
t/04-attach-cid-encoded.t .................... ok
t/04-attach.t ................................ ok
t/05-customxml.t ............................. ok
t/06-modules.t ............................... ok
t/08-schema.t ................................ ok
t/11-cgi.t ................................... skipped: 200 Assumed OK
t/12-cgi_https.t ............................. skipped: 500 Can't connect to localhost:443
t/13-mod_perl.t .............................. skipped: 200 Assumed OK
t/14-cgi_apache.t ............................ skipped: 200 Assumed OK
t/15-daemon.t ................................ skipped: 200 Assumed OK
t/17-mod_soap.t .............................. skipped: 200 Assumed OK
t/19-apachesoap.t ............................ skipped: 500 Can't connect to localhost:8080
t/21-public.t ................................ skipped: 500 Can't connect to services.xmethods.net:80
t/22-interop_apache.t ........................ skipped: 500 Can't connect to nagoya.apache.org:5049
t/23-ppm.t ................................... skipped: ActiveState's ppmserver.pl server seems to be broken - skipping tests
t/24-wsdl.t .................................. skipped: 500 Can't connect to services.xmethods.net:80
t/36-leaks.t ................................. ok
t/38-packager.t .............................. ok
t/40-loopback.t .............................. ok
t/Issues/rt15176.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt53375.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt70329.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt70381.t ........................... skipped: This is a performance test. Set PROFILE_PERFORMANCE env var to a true value to run
t/Issues/rt72836.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt74029.t ........................... skipped: not fixed yet
t/Issues/rt74308.t ........................... Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in pattern match (m//) at /home/<user_profile_name>/SOAP-Lite-1.14/blib/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 340.
Use of uninitialized value $input_name in string eq at /home/<user_profile_name>/SOAP-Lite-1.14/blib/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3193.
Use of uninitialized value $input_name in string eq at /home/<user_profile_name>/SOAP-Lite-1.14/blib/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 3193.
t/Issues/rt74308.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt75169.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt78588.t ........................... ok
t/Issues/rt88915.t ........................... ok
t/release-kwalitee.t ......................... skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
t/release-pod-syntax.t ....................... skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
t/SOAP/Data.t ................................ ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema1999.t ..... ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.t ..... ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_1.t .. ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_2.t .. ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Packager.t ....................... ok
t/SOAP/Schema/WSDL.t ......................... ok
t/SOAP/Serializer.t .......................... ok
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.t ...................... ok
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t .................. Illegal field name '!A:' at /home/<user_profile_name>/SOAP-Lite-1.14/blib/lib/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm line 607.
Use of uninitialized value $error[0] in join or string at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/Carp.pm line 455.
 at t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t line 52.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t .................. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run
t/SOAP/Transport/IO.t ........................ ok
t/SOAP/Transport/LOCAL.t ..................... ok
t/SOAP/Transport/LOOPBACK.t .................. ok
t/SOAP/Transport/MAILTO.t .................... ok
t/SOAP/Transport/POP3.t ...................... ok
t/SOAP/Transport/TCP.t ....................... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t                (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=55, Tests=903, 21 wallclock secs ( 0.14 usr  0.09 sys +  5.48 cusr  4.58 csys = 10.29 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/55 test programs. 0/903 subtests failed.
Makefile:1044: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

---

```
$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 14 subversion 4) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=cygwin, osvers=1.7.35(0.28653), archname=cygwin-thread-multi
    uname='cygwin_nt-6.3 cygwin 1.7.35(0.28653) 2015-02-16 13:03 x86_64 cygwin '
    config_args='-d -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dmksymlinks -Dusethreads -Darchname=x86_64-cygwin-threads -Dlibperl=cygperl5_14.dll -Dcc=gcc -Dld=g++ -Accflags=-ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/src/perl-5.14.4=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fwrapv'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/src/perl-5.14.4=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector',
    optimize='-O3',
    cppflags='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/maint/perl.x86_64/src/perl-5.14.4=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.14.4-3 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.9.2', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='g++', ldflags =' -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib
    libs=-lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lcrypt -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-ldl -lcrypt
    libc=/usr/lib/libc.a, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=cygperl5_14.dll
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' --shared  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
                        PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV USE_64_BIT_ALL USE_64_BIT_INT
                        USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
        rurban/0c612ce82        Fix building static extensions on cygwin, -UUSEIMPORTLIB
        perl.cygwin_autorebase  Rebase DLL after building (skip for cygport builds)
        v5.14.0-RC2-6-gfc6f691  skip testing cygwin utf8 readdir() with Win32 ANSI API
        v5.14.0-RC2-7-g3877b86  Fix test 50 on cygwin: \WINDOWS
        v5.14.0-RC2-10-gd22b5bd revert +x global.sym from 3691eaa79cc6a
        v5.15.0-579-g8375c93    Export store_cop_label for the perl compiler
        v5.15.3-232-g1bac5ec    sv.c: S_anonymise_cv_maybe UTF8 cleanup.
        v5.15.7-75-g803e389     CYG17 utf8 paths
        v5.15.7-302-g5bc802d    Revise perlcygwin.pod for cygwin-1.7
        v5.15.7-303-g286f819    add Cygwin::sync_winenv [perl #110190]
        v5.19.8-494-g6cc44f6    avoid a "FILE" name conflict with cygwin's wchar.h
        v5.19.8-496-g3383030    [perl #120936] op/taint.t handling of no ipcsysv on cygwin
        v5.19.8-509-g288d0d9    cygwin doesn't implement $^E (except as a read of $!)
        v5.21.4-548-g860874c    wrap the failing call_checker test in an eval and TODO it
  Built under cygwin
  Compiled at Feb 17 2015 21:41:24
  @INC:
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.14
    .
```